# error in first gcc cross compiler compile stage (arm-none-eabi/bin/as: unrecognized option '--64')

Tags: gcc, compilation, arm

I'm following a gcc baremetal cross compiler build process. Below is the instruction about ARM GCC stage 1.

```
  5. Configure, build and install ARM GCC stage 1.  This step creates a
     bootstrap ARM toolchain without any of the standard C libraries. Note that
     in the following commands any text within square brackets must only be used
     when building the arm-none-eabi (or armeb-none-eabi) toolchain.
     You do not type the square brackets themselves, only the text between them.

       $ cd build-<target>/gcc_stage1
       $ ../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/configure --target=<target>                     \
                                                --prefix=<install_dir>                \
                                                --with-arch=armv8-a                   \
                                                [--with-fpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8]     \
                                                --disable-multilib                    \
                                                --disable-werror                      \
                                                --enable-languages=c                  \
                                                --disable-shared                      \
                                                --without-headers                     \
                                                --with-newlib                         \
                                                --with-gnu-as                         \
                                                --with-gnu-ld
       $ make all-gcc <-- error here "--64"
       $ make install-gcc
       $ cd ../..
```

For the configuration, I gave command

```
../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/opt/arm-toolchain --with-arch=armv8-a --with-fpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-languages=c --disable-shared --without-headers --with-newlib --with-gu-as --with-gnu-ld
```

And then, when I run `make all-gcc`, I get below error. (Only the last part is shown for brevity, this log is after giving the command second time, so only the last error part is shown).

```
TARGET_CPU_DEFAULT="" \
HEADERS="auto-host.h ansidecl.h" DEFINES="" \
/bin/bash ../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/mkconfig.sh config.h
config.h is unchanged
TARGET_CPU_DEFAULT="TARGET_CPU_generic" \
HEADERS="options.h insn-constants.h config/dbxelf.h config/elfos.h config/arm/unknown-elf.h config/arm/elf.h config/arm/bpabi.h config/newlib-stdint.h config/arm/aout.h config/vxworks-dummy.h config/arm/arm.h config/initfini-array.h defaults.h" DEFINES="LIBC_GLIBC=1 LIBC_UCLIBC=2 LIBC_BIONIC=3 LIBC_MUSL=4" \
/bin/bash ../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/mkconfig.sh tm.h
tm.h is unchanged
TARGET_CPU_DEFAULT="" \
HEADERS="config/arm/arm-protos.h config/arm/aarch-common-protos.h tm-preds.h" DEFINES="" \
/bin/bash ../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/mkconfig.sh tm_p.h
tm_p.h is unchanged
TARGET_CPU_DEFAULT="" \
HEADERS="auto-host.h ansidecl.h" DEFINES="" \
/bin/bash ../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/mkconfig.sh bconfig.h
bconfig.h is unchanged
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc -I../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/build -I../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/../include  -I../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/../libcpp/include  \
    -o build/genmddeps.o ../../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/gcc/genmddeps.c
/opt/arm-toolchain/arm-none-eabi/bin/as: unrecognized option '--64'
Makefile:2428: recipe for target 'build/genmddeps.o' failed
make[1]: *** [build/genmddeps.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ckim/Downloads/arm-toolchain/build-arm-none-eabi/gcc_stage1/gcc'
Makefile:4108: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

The log shows the `as` that I built just before this is being used correctly. I searched the web but couldn't find the same case. Can anybody give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely that you have a mismatch between the ARM architecture you seems to be targeting, `armv8-a`, which is a 64 bit architecture, and the toolchain you are building, `arm-none-eabi`: you should target `aarch64-none-elf` instead: this would be something like:

```
../../gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.05/configure --target=aarch64-elf --prefix=/opt/arm-toolchain --with-arch=armv8-a --with-fpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-languages=c --disable-shared --without-headers --with-newlib --with-gu-as --with-gnu-ld
```

The ARM gcc toolchain was built using the following options:

```
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/9.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-none-elf
Configured with: /tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/gcc/configure --target=aarch64-none-elf --prefix=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/build-aarch64-none-elf/install// --with-gmp=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/build-aarch64-none-elf/host-tools --with-mpfr=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/build-aarch64-none-elf/host-tools --with-mpc=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/build-aarch64-none-elf/host-tools --with-isl=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm1--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/build-aarch64-none-elf/host-tools --disable-shared --disable-nls --disable-threads --disable-tls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-newlib --with-pkgversion='GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.linaro.org/
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10))
```

Comment: Thanks, then, you mean I should remove `--with-arch=armv8-a` in the configuration? I can try tomorrow.

Comment: I just augmented my answer.

Comment: By the way, if this or any answer has solved your question (I think it has), please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)  by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Whether or not the procedure you are using will work or not is a different topic and may lead to more questions.

Comment: you need to use aarch64-whatever-as not arm-whatever-as.   arm-whatever-as wont built for aarch64.  Different gnu targets (different, completely incompatible instruction sets).

Comment: armv8-a if that is supported at all with arm-whatever-whatever may simply actually build for aarch32 the armv7-a compatibility feature.

Comment: @Frant I was supposed to run the commands twice, first for arm-none-eabi and second for aarch64-none-elf. This error came out when I was doing for arm-none-eabi. I tried removing --with-arch=armv8-a but it gave me another error, 'couldnt compile gcc' (something like that). maybe I'll try old_timers method.

Comment: doesn't armv8-a support 32 bit compile? so I was building arm-none-eabi. I was going to after then build aarch64-none-elf.

Comment: I have a working version of arm-none-eabi (executable) received from arm, by arm-none-eabi -v, I could see how it had been configured. There were some differences, so I tried removing --with-arch=armv8-a and -- with-fpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 to remove some differences but I got error : configure: error: in `/home/ckim/Downloads/arm-toolchain/build-arm-none-eabi/gcc_stage1/gcc':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
Makefile:4059: recipe for target 'configure-gcc' failed

Comment: armv8-a does support executing programs compiled for aarch32. But you cannot for example link aarch32 and aarch64 code together, the way you can do with arm32/thumb code.You can use the arm-none-eabi toolchain for compiling aarch32 code. For the aarch64 toolchain, I would suggest you to use a toolchain built by ARM. You can download one [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

so.s:

```
nop
```

build for arm (aarch32)

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
```

build for aarch64 (64 bit arm)

```
aarch64-none-elf-as so.s -o so.o
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   d503201f    nop
```

and mips for demonstration purposes

```
mips-elf-as so.s -o so.o
mips-elf-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-bigmips


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   00000000    nop
```

x86

```
as so.s -o so.o
objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   90                      nop
```

two different instruction sets two different gnu targets just like x86, mips, and arm are different targets and different builds of the gnu tools.

Upvote Frants answer btw this is just a demonstration of that answer.